# How to do alpha numeric sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are my data

```
Transmitter #1
Transmitter #10
Transmitter #11
Transmitter #2
Transmitter #3
Transmitter #4
Transmitter #5
Transmitter #6
Transmitter #7
Transmitter #8
Transmitter #9
Room 1 Transmitter
Allergy Guard – 1
Allergy Guard – 2
Allergy Guard – 3
Deli Counter
```

How to sort these data as alphanumeric.

```
SELECT * FROM #table 
ORDER BY 
Name,
CASE 
    WHEN 
    patindex('%[0-9]%',substring(Name,len(Name),LEN(Name))) =1 
  THEN
        cast(substring(Name,patindex('%[0-9]%', Name),len(Name)) as int)
  END
```

Comment: Allergy Guard – 1

Allergy Guard – 2

Allergy Guard – 3

Transmitter #1

Transmitter #10

Transmitter #11

Transmitter #2

Transmitter #3

Transmitter #4

Transmitter #5

Transmitter #6

Transmitter #7

Transmitter #8

Transmitter #9

Deli Counter

Room 1 Transmitter

Comment: You mean that `Transmitter #9` should come before `Transmitter #10`?

Comment: Sorry here is my correct output 

Allergy Guard – 1

Allergy Guard – 2

Allergy Guard – 3

Transmitter #1

Transmitter #2

Transmitter #3

Transmitter #4

Transmitter #5

Transmitter #6

Transmitter #7

Transmitter #8

Transmitter #9

Transmitter #10

Transmitter #11

Deli Counter

Room 1 Transmitter

Comment: why deli counter came after Transmitter?

Comment: Well, deli counter can come before Transmitter. that makes sense

Comment: There is no standard logic in this world where Deli Counter is the penultimate row and Room 1 is last row. You have custom sort requirements - start searching the internet for previous discussions and solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following keys should sort these in the order you want them:

- Sort by everything before the first number (if any)
- Then by the length ascending
- Then the value ascending

So:

```
order by left(name, patindex('%[0-9]%', name + '0') - 1),
         len(name),
         name
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c53618539445faf8ded8f7adae10e67) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Not giving correct sort. based on your logic 

Allergy Guard – 1
Allergy Guard – 2
Allergy Guard – 3
Deli Counter
Room 1 Transmitter
Transmitter #1
Transmitter #10
Transmitter #11
Transmitter #2
Transmitter #3
Transmitter #4
Transmitter #5
Transmitter #6
Transmitter #7
Transmitter #8
Transmitter #9

-------------------------------------------
Transmitter #10
Transmitter #11

is not getting sorted

Comment: I was trying this.

create table #test(
name varchar(Max)  NULL,
)



insert into #test values(
'Transmitter #1'),
('Transmitter #10'),
('Transmitter #11'),
('Transmitter #2'),
('Transmitter #3'),
('Transmitter #4'),
('Transmitter #5'),
('Transmitter #6'),
('Transmitter #7'),
('Transmitter #8'),
('Transmitter #9'),
('Room 1 Transmitter'),
('Allergy Guard – 1'),
('Allergy Guard – 2'),
('Allergy Guard – 3'),
('Deli Counter')


SELECT * FROM #test 

order by left(name, patindex('%[0-9]%', name + '0')),
         len(name),
         name

Comment: @JohnAbraham . . . I'm utterly baffled how you can say that when I have included a db<>fiddle that shows ordering that you want.